# If the range of the function $f(x)=\frac{x^2+ax+b}{x^2+2x+3}$ is $[-5,4],a,b\in N$,then find the value of $a^2+b^2.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

If the range of the function $f(x)=\frac{x^2+ax+b}{x^2+2x+3}$ is $[-5,4],a,b\in N$,then find the value of $a^2+b^2.$

---

Let $y=\frac{x^2+ax+b}{x^2+2x+3}$
$$x^2y+2xy+3y=x^2+ax+b$$
$$x^2(y-1)+x(2y-a)+3y-b=0$$
As $x$ is real,so the discriminant of the above quadratic equation has to be greater than or equal to zero.
$$(2y-a)^2-4(y-1)(3y-b)\geq0$$
$$-8y^2+y(-4a+4b+12)+a^2-4b\geq0$$
As above quadratic inequality is greater than or equal to zero,so its discriminant is less than or equal to zero.
$$(-4a+4b+12)^2+32(a^2-4b)\leq0$$
I am stuck here,i cant find $a^2+b^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$-5 \le \frac{x^2+ax+b}{x^2+2x+3} \le 4 $$
As the denominator is positive, this is equivalent to
$$-5x^2-10x-15 \le x^2+ax+b \le 4x^2+8x + 12$$
which can be considered as two quadratic inequalities,
$$6x^2+(a+10)x+(b+15) \ge 0, \quad 3x^2+(8-a)x+(12-b) \ge 0$$
Note that equality must happen as well for some $x$. For this to be true for all reals, the discriminants must be then zero, and $-15 \le b \le 12$ to ensure the quadratics are both above the x axis. So
$$(a+10)^2 = 24(b+15), \quad (8-a)^2 = 12(12-b)$$
Solving, $a=14$ and $b = 9$ giving $a^2+b^2 = 277$.

Comment: Can't the discriminants be less than zero?

Comment: @TheOddbodNumber then you won't ever touch th x axis, which means it won't give a max or min, only upper and lower bounds.

Comment: If $b$ is not in those bounds, check what happens to the inequalities when $x=0$.

Comment: Hope my earlier comment on the discriminant clarified.  If the discriminant is negative, you don't have roots, so the inequality is never an equality, so you don't have the maximum / minimum achieved actually.

Comment: Yes it is clear to me now,thanks@Macavity

Comment: The key is if you have an inequality like $f(x)< 4$, this does not mean $4$ is the maximum, it is just an upper bound.  However if you have $f(x) \le 4$ and you know for some value $f(x_0)=4$, then you have the maximum.

Answer (score 2):

Begin with
$$g(y)=-8y^2+y(-4a+4b+12)+a^2-4b\geq 0,\quad\forall y\in[-5,4].$$
Then we wish to solve $g(-5)=g(4)=0$, that is,
\begin{align}
-200-5(-4a+4b+12)+a^2-4b=0,\\
-128+4(-4a+4b+12)+a^2-4b=0,
\end{align}
or 
\begin{align}
a^2+20a-24b&=260,\\
a^2-16a+12b&=80.
\end{align}
Thus
\begin{align}
a-b=5\quad\mbox{and}\quad
0=a^2-4a-140=(a-14)(a+10)
\end{align}
and we obtain two sets of solutions 
$$a=14,\,b=9\quad\mbox{and}\quad
  a=-10,\,b=-15.$$
where the second solution does not fit because $a,$ $b$ are assumed to be positive integers. Hence $a^2+b^2=277.$